# Bootstrap 3.0 vertical align inside column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap 3 layout with the following structure:

```
<div class="row row-full">
     <div class="col col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <div class="row row-middle">
               <h1>Some Title</h1>
               <h3>SubTitle</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="row row-bottom">
               <h1>Some Title</h1>
               <h3>SubTitle</h3>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

And this is my customization with the CSS:

```
.row-full{
     height:100%;
}

.row-full .col{
     height:100%;
}

.row-bottom, .row-middle{
     height:50%;
}
```

And I end up with the following layout from a large screen:

```
--------------------------------------
|     Title          |               |
|     SubTitle       |               |
|                    |               |
--------------------------------------
|     Title          |               |
|     SubTitle       |               |
|                    |               |
--------------------------------------
```

So in my layout the main row takes 100% of the screen and same applies for the column. Each sub-row, takes 50% of the height but I need also to be able to set the vertical alignment inside the column because it is a responsive layout.
I tried with FlexBox but it mess up my grid system. 
What is the correct way by using Bootstrap 3.0?
What I need is the ability to vertical align the content inside the rows.

Comment: Vertical-align only works for inline elements.

Comment: So the alternatives are:
- Calculate with JS at runtime the padding 
- Transform into Table and Table-Cell?

Comment: That may fix your problem. It's a nice way to go too. You also should consider the margin that the header tags have too. That will throw it off. The container is growing with the elements inside. See these two pens: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjOBPr  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPqzWW 

Note: Not solutions...I don't think.